# Вопрос по плагину Owl Carousel jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать вот такую навигацию ?
Я пытался сделать абсолютное позиционирование, но так как слайдер адаптивный, на разных разрешениях он уезжают немного в сторону.
Структура плагина такова, что блок с навигацией лежит под блоком карусели. Как его переместить внутрь - не знаю, структура формируется через js.
Надеюсь на помощь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    /*
 *  jQuery OwlCarousel v1.15
 *  
 *  Copyright (c) 2013 Bartosz Wojciechowski
 *  http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel
 *
 *  Licensed under MIT
 *
 */


// Object.create function
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function( obj ) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    };
}
(function( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    var Carousel = {
        init :function(options, el){
            var base = this;
            base.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.owlCarousel.options, options);

            var elem = el;
            var $elem = $(el);
            base.$elem = $elem;

            base.baseClass();

            //Hide and get Heights
            base.$elem
            .css({opacity: 0,
                "display":"block"})

            base.checkTouch();
            base.support3d();

            base.wrapperWidth = 0;
            base.currentSlide = 0; //Starting Position

            base.userItems = $elem.children();
            base.itemsAmount = base.userItems.length;
            base.wrapItems();

            base.owlItems = base.$elem.find(".owl-item");
            base.owlWrapper = base.$elem.find(".owl-wrapper");

            base.orignalItems = base.options.items;
            base.playDirection = "next";

            base.onstartup = true;

            //setTimeout(function(){
            base.updateVars();
            //},0);
        },

        baseClass : function(){
            var base = this;
            var hasBaseClass = base.$elem.hasClass(base.options.baseClass);
            var hasThemeClass = base.$elem.hasClass(base.options.theme);

            if(!hasBaseClass){
                base.$elem.addClass(base.options.baseClass);
            }

            if(!hasThemeClass){
                base.$elem.addClass(base.options.theme);
            }

        },

        updateSize : function(){
            var base = this;

            var width = $(window).width();

            if(width > (base.options.itemsDesktop[0] || base.orignalItems) ){
                 base.options.items = base.orignalItems
            } 

            if(width <= base.options.itemsDesktop[0] && base.options.itemsDesktop !== false){
                base.options.items = base.options.itemsDesktop[1];
            }  

            if(width <= base.options.itemsDesktopSmall[0] && base.options.itemsDesktopSmall !== false){
                base.options.items = base.options.itemsDesktopSmall[1];
            }  

            if(width <= base.options.itemsTablet[0]  && base.options.itemsTablet !== false){
                base.options.items = base.options.itemsTablet[1];
            } 

            if(width <= base.options.itemsMobile[0] && base.options.itemsMobile !== false){
                base.options.items = base.options.itemsMobile[1];
            }

        },
        updateVars : function(){
            var base = this;

            if(base.options.responsive === true){
                base.updateSize();
            }

            base.calculateAll();

            //Only on startup
            if(base.onstartup === true){

                base.buildControlls();

                if(base.options.responsive === true){
                    base.response();
                }

                base.moveEvents();
                base.play();
                base.$elem.animate({opacity: 1});
                base.onstartup = false;
            }

            base.updatePagination();
        },

        response : function(){
            var base = this,
                width,
                smallDelay;

            $(window).resize(function(){
                if(base.options.autoPlay !== false){
                    clearInterval(base.myInterval);
                }
                clearTimeout(smallDelay)
                smallDelay = setTimeout(function(){

                    base.update();

                },200);
            })
        },

        update : function(){
            var base = this;

            base.updateVars();
            if(base.support3d === true){
                if(base.positionsInArray[base.currentSlide] > base.maximumPixels){
                    base.transition3d(base.positionsInArray[base.currentSlide]);
                } else {
                    base.transition3d(0);
                    base.currentSlide = 0 //in array
                }
            } else{
                if(base.positionsInArray[base.currentSlide] > base.maximumPixels){
                    base.css2slide(base.positionsInArray[base.currentSlide]);
                } else {
                    base.css2slide(0);
                    base.currentSlide = 0 //in array
                }
            }
            if(base.options.autoPlay !== false){
                base.play();
            }

        },

        wrapItems : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.userItems.wrapAll("<div class=\"owl-wrapper\">").wrap("<div class=\"owl-item\"></div>");
        },

        appendItemsSizes : function(){
            var base = this;

            var roundPages = 0;
            var lastItem = base.itemsAmount - base.options.items

            base.owlItems.each(function(index){
                $(this)
                .css({"width": base.itemWidth})
                .data("owl-item",Number(index));

                if(index % base.options.items === 0 || index === lastItem){
                    if(!(index > lastItem)){
                        roundPages +=1;
                    }
                }
                $(this).data("owl-roundPages",roundPages);
                base.wrapperWidth =  base.wrapperWidth+ base.itemWidth
            })
        },

        appendWrapperSizes : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.owlWrapper.css({
                //add one more pixel to fix ie9 bug
                "width": base.wrapperWidth+1,
                "left": 0
            });
        },

        calculateAll : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.calculateWidth();
            base.appendItemsSizes();
            base.appendWrapperSizes();
            base.loops();
            base.max();
        },

        calculateWidth : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.itemWidth = Math.round(base.$elem.width()/base.options.items)
        },

        max : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.maximumSlide = base.itemsAmount - base.options.items;
            var maximum = (base.itemsAmount * base.itemWidth) - base.options.items * base.itemWidth;
                maximum = maximum * -1
            base.maximumPixels = maximum;
            return maximum;
        },

        min : function(){
            return 0;
        },

        loops : function(){
            var base = this;

            base.positionsInArray = [0];
            var elWidth = 0;

            for(var i = 0; i<base.itemsAmount; i++){
                elWidth += base.itemWidth;
                base.positionsInArray.push(-elWidth)
            }
        },

        buildControlls : function(){
            var base = this;

            if(base.options.navigation === true || base.options.pagination === true){
                base.owlControlls = $("<div class=\"owl-controlls\"/>").appendTo(base.$elem)
            }
            if (base.isTouch === false){
                base.owlControlls.addClass("clickable")
            }

            if(base.options.pagination === true){
                base.buildPagination();
            }
            if(base.options.navigation === true){
                base.buildButtons();
            }

        },

        buildButtons : function(){
            var base = this;
            var buttonsWrapper = $("<div class=\"owl-buttons\"/>")
            base.owlControlls.append(buttonsWrapper)

            base.buttonPrev = $("<div/>",{
                "class" : "owl-prev",
                "text" : base.options.navigationText[0] || ""
                });

            base.buttonNext = $("<div/>",{
                "class" : "owl-next",
                "text" : base.options.navigationText[1] || ""
                });

            buttonsWrapper
            .append(base.buttonPrev)
            .append(base.buttonNext);

            buttonsWrapper.on( base.getEvent() , "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                if($(this).hasClass('owl-next')){
                    base.next();
                } else{
                    base.prev();
                } 
            })

            //Add 'disable' class
            base.checkNavigation();
        },

        getEvent : function(){
            var base = this;
            if (base.isTouch === true){
                return "touchstart.owlControlls"
            } else {
                return "click.owlControlls"
            }
        },

        buildPagination : function(){
            var base = this;

            base.paginationWrapper = $("<div class=\"owl-pagination\"/>");
            base.owlControlls.append(base.paginationWrapper);

            base.paginationWrapper.on(base.getEvent(), ".owl-page", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                if(Number($(this).data("owl-page")) !== base.currentSlide){
                    base.goTo( Number($(this).data("owl-page")), true)
                }
            });
            base.updatePagination();

        },

        updatePagination : function(){
            var base = this;
            if(base.options.pagination === false){
                return false;
            }
            base.paginationWrapper.html("");

            var counter = 0;
            var lastPage = base.itemsAmount - base.itemsAmount % base.options.items

            for(var i = 0; i<base.itemsAmount; i++){
                if(i % base.options.items === 0){
                    counter +=1
                    if(lastPage === i){
                        var lastItem = base.itemsAmount - base.options.items
                    }
                    var paginationButton = $("<div/>",{
                        "class" : "owl-page"
                        });
                    var paginationButtonInner = $("<span></span>",{
                        "text": base.options.paginationNumbers === true ? counter : "",
                        "class": base.options.paginationNumbers === true ? "owl-numbers" : ""
                    });
                    paginationButton.append(paginationButtonInner)

                    paginationButton.data("owl-page",lastPage === i ? lastItem : i);
                    paginationButton.data("owl-roundPages",counter);

                    base.paginationWrapper.append(paginationButton)
                }
            }
            base.checkPagination();
        },
        checkPagination : function(arg){
            var base = this;

            base.paginationWrapper.find(".owl-page").each(function(i,v){
                if($(this).data("owl-roundPages") === $(base.owlItems[base.currentSlide]).data("owl-roundPages") ){
                //Subject to discuss
                //if($(this).data("owl-page") == base.currentSlide){
                    base.paginationWrapper
                    .find(".owl-page")
                    .removeClass("active")
                    //.removeAttr("disabled", "disabled");
                    //$(this).addClass("active").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                } 
            });
        },

        checkNavigation : function(){
            var base = this;

            if(base.currentSlide === 0){
                base.buttonPrev.addClass('disabled');
                base.buttonNext.removeClass('disabled');

            } else if (base.currentSlide === base.maximumSlide){
                base.buttonPrev.removeClass('disabled');
                base.buttonNext.addClass('disabled');

            } else if(base.currentSlide !== 0 && base.currentSlide !== base.maximumSlide){
                base.buttonPrev.removeClass('disabled');
                base.buttonNext.removeClass('disabled');
            }
        },

        destroyControlls : function(){
            var base = this;
            if(base.owlControlls){
                base.owlControlls.remove();
            }
        },

        next : function(speed){
            var base = this;
            base.currentSlide += 1;
            if(base.currentSlide > base.maximumSlide){
                base.currentSlide = base.maximumSlide;
                return false;
            }
            base.goTo(base.currentSlide,speed);
        },

        prev : function(speed){
            var base = this;
            base.currentSlide -= 1
            if(base.currentSlide < 0){
                base.currentSlide = 0;
                return false;
            }
            base.goTo(base.currentSlide,speed);
        },

        goTo : function(position,pagination){
            var base = this;
            if(position >= base.maximumSlide){
                position = base.maximumSlide
            } 
            else if( position <= 0 ){
                position = 0
            }
            base.currentSlide = position;

            var goToPixel = base.positionsInArray[position];

            if(base.support3d === true){
                base.isCss3Finish = false;

                if(pagination === true){
                    base.swapTransitionSpeed("paginationSpeed");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        base.isCss3Finish = true;
                    }, base.options.paginationSpeed);

                } else if(pagination === "goToFirst" ){
                    base.swapTransitionSpeed(base.options.goToFirstSpeed);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        base.isCss3Finish = true;
                    }, base.options.goToFirstSpeed);

                } else {
                    base.swapTransitionSpeed("slideSpeed");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        base.isCss3Finish = true;
                    }, base.options.slideSpeed);
                }
                base.transition3d(goToPixel);
            } else {
                if(pagination === true){
                    base.css2slide(goToPixel, base.options.paginationSpeed);
                } else if(pagination === "goToFirst" ){
                    base.css2slide(goToPixel, base.options.goToFirstSpeed);
                } else {
                    base.css2slide(goToPixel, base.options.slideSpeed);
                }
            }

            if(base.options.pagination === true){
                base.checkPagination()
            }
            if(base.options.navigation === true){
                base.checkNavigation()
            }
            if(base.options.autoPlay !== false){
                base.play()
            }
        },

        stop: function(){
            var base = this;
            base.options.autoPlay = false;
            clearInterval(base.myInterval);
        },

        play : function(){
            var base = this;
            if(base.options.autoPlay === false){
                return false;
            }
            clearInterval(base.myInterval);
            base.myInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if(base.currentSlide < base.maximumSlide && base.playDirection === "next"){
                    base.next(true);
                } else if(base.currentSlide === base.maximumSlide){
                    if(base.options.goToFirst === true){
                        base.goTo(0,"goToFirst");
                    } else{
                        base.playDirection = "prev";
                        base.prev(true);
                    }
                } else if(base.playDirection === "prev" && base.currentSlide > 0){
                    base.prev(true);
                } else if(base.playDirection === "prev" && base.currentSlide === 0){
                    base.playDirection = "next";
                    base.next(true);
                }
            },base.options.autoPlay)    
        },

        swapTransitionSpeed : function(action){
            var base = this;
            if(action === "slideSpeed"){
                base.owlWrapper.css(base.addTransition(base.options.slideSpeed));
            } else if(action === "paginationSpeed" ){
                base.owlWrapper.css(base.addTransition(base.options.paginationSpeed));
            } else if(typeof action !== "string"){
                base.owlWrapper.css(base.addTransition(action));
            }
        },

        addTransition : function(speed){
            var base = this;            
            return {
                "-webkit-transition": "all "+ speed +"ms ease",
                "-moz-transition": "all "+ speed +"ms ease",
                "-o-transition": "all "+ speed +"ms ease",
                "transition": "all "+ speed +"ms ease"
            }
        },
        removeTransition : function(){
            return {
                "-webkit-transition": "",
                "-moz-transition": "",
                "-o-transition": "",
                "transition": ""
            }
        },

        doTranslate : function(pixels){
            return { 
                "-webkit-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
                "-moz-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
                "-o-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
                "-ms-transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px, 0px)",
                "transform": "translate3d("+pixels+"px, 0px,0px)"
                };
        },

        transition3d : function(value){
            var base = this;
            base.owlWrapper.css(base.doTranslate(value));
        },
        css2move : function(value){
            var base = this;
            base.owlWrapper.css({"left" : value})
        },
        css2slide : function(value,speed){
            var base = this;

            base.isCssFinish = false;
            base.owlWrapper.stop(true,true).animate({
                "left" : value
            }, {
                duration : speed || base.options.slideSpeed ,
                complete : function(){
                    base.isCssFinish = true;
                }
            })
        },

        support3d : function(){
                var base = this;

                var sTranslate3D = "translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)";
                var eTemp = document.createElement("div");
                eTemp.style.cssText = "  -moz-transform:"    + sTranslate3D +
                                      "; -ms-transform:"     + sTranslate3D +
                                      "; -o-transform:"      + sTranslate3D +
                                      "; -webkit-transform:" + sTranslate3D +
                                      "; transform:"         + sTranslate3D;
                var rxTranslate = /translate3d\(0px, 0px, 0px\)/g;
                var asSupport = eTemp.style.cssText.match(rxTranslate);
                var bHasSupport = (asSupport !== null && asSupport.length === 1);
                base.support3d = bHasSupport
                return bHasSupport;
        },

        checkTouch : function(){
            var base = this;
            if ("ontouchstart" in document.documentElement)
            {
                base.isTouch = true;
            } else {
                base.isTouch = false;
            }
        },



        //Touch
        moveEvents : function(check){

            var base = this,
                offsetX = 0,
                offsetY = 0,
                baseElWidth = 0,
                relativePos = 0,
                minSwipe,
                maxSwipe,
                sliding;

            var links = base.$elem.find('a');

            base.isCssFinish = true;

            var start = function(event){
                if(base.isCssFinish === false){
                    return false;
                } 
                if(base.isCss3Finish === false){
                    return false;
                }

                var oEvent = event.originalEvent,
                    pos = $(this).position();
                    base.newRelativeX = 0;

                if(base.options.autoPlay !== false){
                    clearInterval(base.myInterval);
                }
                $(this)
                .css(base.removeTransition())

                base.newX = 0;

                relativePos = pos.left;

                if(base.isTouch === true){
                    offsetX = oEvent.touches[0].pageX - pos.left;
                    offsetY = oEvent.touches[0].pageY - pos.top;
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("grabbing");
                    offsetX = event.pageX - pos.left;
                    offsetY = event.pageY - pos.top;
                    $(document).on("mousemove.owl", move);
                    $(document).on("mouseup.owl", end);
                }

                sliding = false;
                if(jQuery._data( base.$elem.get(0), "events" ).touchmove === undefined){
                    base.$elem.on("touchmove.owl", ".owl-wrapper", move);
                }

            };

            var move = function(event){
                var oEvent = event.originalEvent;

                if(base.isTouch === true){
                    base.newX = oEvent.touches[0].pageX - offsetX;
                    base.newY = oEvent.touches[0].pageY - offsetY;

                } else {
                    base.newX = event.pageX - offsetX;
                }

                base.newRelativeX = base.newX - relativePos

                if(base.newRelativeX > 8 || base.newRelativeX < -8  ){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    sliding = true;
                }

                if(  (base.newY > 10 || base.newY < -10) && sliding === false  ){
                     base.$elem.off("touchmove.owl");
                }

                minSwipe = function(){
                    return  base.newRelativeX / 5;
                }
                maxSwipe = function(){
                    return  base.maximumPixels + base.newRelativeX / 5;
                }
                //Calculate min and max
                base.newX = Math.max(Math.min( base.newX, minSwipe() ), maxSwipe() );
                if(base.support3d === true){
                    base.transition3d(base.newX);
                } else {
                    base.css2move(base.newX);
                }

            };

             var end = function(event){

                if(base.isTouch === true){
                    var $this = $(this);
                } else{
                    var $this = base.owlWrapper
                    $this.removeClass("grabbing")
                    $(document).off("mousemove.owl");
                    $(document).off("mouseup.owl");
                }


                if(base.newX !== 0){
                    var newPosition = base.getNewPosition();
                    base.goTo(newPosition)
                } else {
                    if(links.length>0){
                        links.off('click.owlClick');
                    }
                }

            };


            if(base.isTouch === true){
                base.$elem.on("touchstart.owl", ".owl-wrapper", start);
                base.$elem.on("touchend.owl", ".owl-wrapper", end);
            }else{
                links.on('click.owlClick', function(event){event.preventDefault();})
                base.$elem.on("mousedown.owl", ".owl-wrapper", start);              
                base.$elem.on('dragstart.owl',"img", function(event) { event.preventDefault();});
                base.$elem.bind('mousedown.disableTextSelect', function() {return false;});
             }
        },

        clearEvents : function(){
            var base = this;
            base.$elem.off('.owl');
            $(document).off('.owl');
        },

        getNewPosition : function(){
            var base = this,
                newPosition;

            //Calculate new Position
            var newPosition = base.improveClosest();

            if(newPosition>base.maximumSlide){
                base.currentSlide = base.maximumSlide;
                newPosition  = base.maximumSlide;
            } else if( base.newX >=0 ){
                newPosition = 0;
                base.currentSlide = 0;
            }
            return newPosition;
        },

        improveClosest : function(){
            var base = this;
            var array = base.positionsInArray;
            var goal = base.newX;
            var closest = null;
            $.each(array, function(i,v){
                if( goal - (base.itemWidth/20) > array[i+1] && goal - (base.itemWidth/20)< v && base.moveDirection() === "left") {
                    closest = v;
                    base.currentSlide = i;
                } 
                else if (goal + (base.itemWidth/20) < v && goal + (base.itemWidth/20) > array[i+1] && base.moveDirection() === "right"){
                    closest = array[i+1];
                    base.currentSlide = i+1;
                }
            });
            return base.currentSlide;
        },

        moveDirection : function(){
            var base = this,
                direction;
            if(base.newRelativeX < 0 ){
                direction = "right"
                base.playDirection = "next"
            } else {
                direction = "left"
                base.playDirection = "prev"
            }
            return direction
        },


        //unused
        closest : function(a,x){
            var base = this;
            var theArray = a;
            var goal = x;
            var closestItem = 0;
            var closest = null;
            $.each(theArray, function(i,v){
              if (closest === null || Math.abs(v - goal) < Math.abs(closest - goal)) {
                closest = v;
              }
            });
            return closest;
        }
    };


    $.fn.owlCarousel = function( options ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var carousel = Object.create( Carousel );
            carousel.init( options, this );
            $.data( this, 'owlCarousel', carousel );
        });
    };

    $.fn.owlCarousel.options = {
        slideSpeed : 200,
        paginationSpeed : 800,

        autoPlay : false,
        goToFirst : true,
        goToFirstSpeed : 1000,

        navigation : false,
        navigationText : ["prev","next"],
        pagination : true,
        paginationNumbers: false,

        responsive: true,

        items : 5,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
        itemsTablet: [768,2],
        itemsMobile : [479,1],

        baseClass : "owl-carousel",
        theme : "owl-theme"
    };

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.owl-theme .owl-controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 45%;
}
```

Либо заменить

```
base.owlControls = $("").toggleClass("clickable", !base.browser.isTouch).appendTo(base.$elem);
```

На

```
base.owlControls = $("").toggleClass("clickable", !base.browser.isTouch).appendTo(base.wrapperOuter);
```

Если на глаз - должно работать.

PS: Это соответственно для последней версии.

Comment: Я такого кода даже не вижу, чтобы заменить. А первый вариант не работает, всё равно позиционирует относительно экрана и на разном разрешении уезжает.

Comment: А это что - base.owlControlls = $("<div class=\"owl-controlls\"/>").appendTo(base.$elem) ?

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю, слайдер не предусматривает такую конструкцию. Если использование данного слайдера не принципиально, обратите внимание на [Фотораму](http://fotorama.io/).

Еще одним выходом вижу создание отдельного блока с превью, который вы адаптируете самостоятельно, и привязку его к слайдеру через [Хэш-мап](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/urlhashnav.html).

Comment: А можете, пожалуйста, объяснить подробнее как вторым способом сделать? Например я стилизовал блок с названием .navstr , как его реализовать в коде?

Comment: Или же можете в js коде реализовать так, чтобы блок с классом .owl-buttons был внутри блока .owl-controlls ? там вроде пару строк местами поменять, а я в js не силен ( 
Вот код скрипта (отредактировал сообщение).

Comment: Не получается так сделать. Картинки адаптивяся и смещаются...